# Arduino mkr1000 does not Serial print upon GET using aRest library

Tags: rest, arduino

I'm trying to create a REST server on an arduino mkr1000. upon searching google i came upon the aRest library which handles most of the stuff i need.

[aRest library documentation](https://github.com/marcoschwartz/aREST/blob/master/README.md)

So i created a sample sketch based on the guides. Here is the code:

```
#include < SPI.h >
#include < WiFi101.h >
#include < aREST.h >

aREST rest = aREST();

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiServer restServer(80);

char ssid[] = "user";  // not actual username
char pass[] = "pass";  // not actual password


int clapMode(String data){
  Serial.println("Request Recieved: " + data);
}


void setup() {

 Serial.begin(115200);

 rest.set_id("000");
 rest.set_name("MKR1000");
 rest.function("test",clapMode);

 while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
   Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
   Serial.println(ssid);
   // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP 
network:
   status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
   // wait 10 seconds for connection:
   delay(10000);
 }

 Serial.println();

 // you're connected now, so print out the status:
 printWifiStatus();

 // Start server
 restServer.begin();
 Serial.println(F("Listening for connections..."));

}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = restServer.available();
    if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }
  rest.handle(client);
}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip); 

  IPAddress subnet = WiFi.subnetMask();
  Serial.print("Netmask: ");
  Serial.println(subnet);

  IPAddress gateway = WiFi.gatewayIP();
  Serial.print("Gateway: ");
  Serial.println(gateway);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

The code works mostly. Upon using POSTMAN to perform a GET the arduino is able to give the appropriate response.

Now for the part that is not working is the endpoint i just have created using this code

```
rest.function("test",clapMode);
```

upon performing a GET in postman, the arduino is able to give a response, but it should perform this code

```
int clapMode(String data){
  Serial.println("Request Recieved: " + data);
}
```

but on my serial Monitor i am not getting anything.

[image: Serial Monitor]

[image: GET Postman]

Also i could not find on how to tailor the response of the arduino from the request. How do i it ?

Thank you very much

Comment: You have to send the request to `<host>/test?params=0`, not `<host>/clapMode`

Comment: oh myyy, how could i not notice that i named the endpoint test! Thank you very much! I think the lack of sleep is getting to me. If you would like you can post it so i can tag it as the correct answer

Comment: Can you help me with the follow up question ? how do i set the response to my desired JSON ?

Comment: What do you want to edit in the response? You can edit the ID and the name in the code. Also you can probably add variables by using the `rest.variable()` function. I guess the rest is hard-coded into the library.

Comment: yes i would like the response to not contain, id,name. but  i would like to still get those info if i use the built in endpoint "id" . It is not really an important, just to make it a little bit more tidy

Comment: They are hard-coded into the library. You have to remove them from the code by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the request to `<host>/test?params=0`, not `<host>/clapMode`.

Furthermore, you can modify the ID and name with

```
rest.set_id("device ID");
rest.set_name("device name");
```

and add variables with

```
rest.variable("variable name", &variable);
```

The response is hard-coded into the library, therefore if you want to add/remove other stuff, you have to edit the library by yourself.